# Are questions about using uncommon software tools for viewing/reading code on topic for SO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I am asking related to this question:
[Trying to view source code for a Houdini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75579454/trying-to-view-source-code-for-a-houdini-file)

[image: Screenshot of answer.]

It seemed like SO is the relevant Stack Exchange site for this question because the goal is to view *code*. I.e., it is asking how to use a software tool to open and inspect the contents of a text file in order to understand how an algorithm was implemented (programmed).

I don't understand why this question would meaningfully diverge from questions about using renderdoc to inspect shader code, how to use a Git UI tool for code review, or any other question which has a non opinion based answer which is about software tools in the context of programming other than it happens to be about Houdini which is somewhat esoteric as a programming tool, but that's only because the constraints of the programming problem (reading the source code of an algorithm) require that tool specifically.

Would this not be similar to asking about how to see the Python code of a [Blender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_%28software%29) extension?

Comment: It seems that you are expecting the model file to contain Python code. Did you try putting `houdini view python code` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=houdini+view+python+code)?

Comment: This question appears to be asking how to use/access the programming view of a tool that supports programming, which indicates that it is on-topic here. Granted, have you tried the Alt+E shortcut?

Comment: _The authors provide the source code as a proprietary binary code that can only be opened in Houdini._ -- That isn't a binary format; I was able to open and inspect the `.hipnc` file with a text editor; I tried both Kate and emacs, and they both worked. Is that not a good enough solution?

Comment: @TylerH The self-deletion is doubly disappointing given that the OP's question has now received enough votes to be reopened. If only some voters were as eager to help improve questions as they are to close them.

Comment: @TylerH it's the consequence of a reputation based system. Keeping the question open with a downvote hurts me more than keeping it open. After the initial wave of people insisting the question was off topic I took it off since it semed it was unanimous.

I have undeleted the question.

Comment: @skomisa I am sorry, given that the question is as it stands lowering my reputation I eventually felt like deleting it was the better option.

Comment: @absurdum That will open the binary, but the binary data in that file is not source code. The source code should be in there however.

Comment: @Makogan No worries, and it's good to see that your question is now open again. As far as getting your actual concern with Houdini resolved, perhaps consider asking on Houdini's [Technical Discussion forum](https://www.sidefx.com/forum/4/)?

Comment: @Makogan Actually, no, deleting a closed question "hurts you" much more than keeping an open, downvoted question around, if you are talking about the system ban on asking question.

Comment: @TylerH Correct. Since the SE system does a poor job of explaining that before people run into that ban, so the mistake is understandable.

Comment: @Makogan are you sure there even IS source code? From a very quick glance at Houdini, it seems similar to a graphical editor for game engines and the like, which allows you to click together things without writing a line of code. See also https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/basics/intro.html. It seems possible that there is no "source code" in the classical sense of handwritten instructions in some language, but that the algorithm is expressed as a combination of nodes and their parameters in the houdini networks.

Comment: It's unfortunate but the answer will be quite apparent to Houdini users who chanced upon the question. I was not one but it took less than an hour to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

On an initial glance, the title/question is written as if it is a "please recommend a tool to view the source code" request which would make it off-topic.

However, if you dig deeper into the question it asks:

> The authors provide the source code as a proprietary binary code that can only be opened in Houdini. A .hipnc file.
>
> [...]
>
> Given the original paper description I know that the source code is contained in the Houdini file. The author's explicitly say so. But I cannot find documentation describing how to see that source code.

This could have been rewritten much more concisely as:

"The authors provide a Houdini binary file (in the proprietary `.hipnc` format) which they state contains embedded source code. How can I extract or view that embedded source code?"

Which reads as a very different question and a solution is not necessarily limited to the Houdini editor. But, since Houdini is (apparently) the tool that is intended to read that file type then it is likely it would be part of the answer and that the answer would revolve around either how the `.hipnc` file format is structured and programmatically extracting the embedded source code or how to use the Houdini editor to view that embedded source code.

Comment: Your suggestion is more concise, and perhaps more precise, but still reads the same way/as the same question; it is certainly not "a very different" question.